What is the right way to check lower timeframe to verify if condition is met
What is the right logic to verify if my "Hit SL Signal" really met in the lower timeframe?
I want to achive if the condition is met plotshape will be trigger:
Like this example it met on the daily timeframe but when i check in the lower timeframe its not so "Hit SL Signal" should not trigger:


Unfortunately, historical bars only have the OHLC price information. So, you cannot really know how the price moved within the bar.
The right logic? You run your indicator on lower timeframes and get the data you need from higher timeframes. Then use the bar replay function to check past data. You can go to the first available bar on your chart with the bar replay function and when you click on that bar, it will load even more (past) bars on your chart.
If the timeframes you use are not too far away from each other, you may try to use request.security_lower_tf(). But with this approach you will also have less data. Because you won't have this lower timeframe information for the first set of bars. It will simply return na. For example, if you are on the daily timeframe and request data from the 1 minute timeframe, you will only have this information for about the last 3 months on the daily chart.
Alternatively, you can implement the assumption done by the strategy broker emulator [Source].

Since the emulator can only use chart data, it makes assumptions about
intrabar price movement. It uses a bar’s open, high, and low prices to
infer intrabar activity while calculating order fills with the
following logic:

If the high price is closer to the opening price than the low price,
it assumes that the price moved in this order on the bar: open → high
→ low → close.
If the low price is closer to the opening price than
the high price, it assumes that the price moved in this order on the
bar: open → low → high → close.
The broker emulator assumes no gaps
exist between prices within bars; in the “eyes” of the emulator, the
full range of intrabar prices is available for order execution.



